# Cant get props from getInitialProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using nextjs-react framework I am using `getInitialProps` function to make initial properties but i cant access to returned values from this function showing `undefined`. My code is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {addName} from '../Actions/actionCreators'
class about extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ req }){
        try{
            const protocol = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http'
            const baseUrl = req ? `${protocol}://${req.headers.host}` : ''
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/config`
            const response = await fetch(url)
            const configJson = await response.json()
            return { apiUrl: url, configs: configJson }
        }catch{
            return { error: 'Could not load configs'}
        }
    }
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { name: '', configs: props.configs }
        this.addname = this.addname.bind(this)
    }
    addname(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        const name = e.target.name.value
        this.setState({ name: name })
        const newName = {
            name : this.state.name
        }
        fetch(this.props.apiUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(newName),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .catch(err => console.error('POST error', err));
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.apiUrl)
        const markup = this.props.name.name.length > 0 ? this.props.name.name.map((elem, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                        {this.props.name.name[i]}
                    </div>
                )) : <p></p>
        return (
            <div>
                <h2> About me </h2>
                {markup}
                <p>This is muaz.I am a programmer and web developer also a doctor.Want To learn Let me know about yourself</p>
                <form action="" onSubmit={this.addname}>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    <br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return{
        submitform : (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            dispatch(addName(e.target.name.value))
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state.name)
    return{
        name : state.name
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(about)
```

I am also using `Redux` gramework with it.It I have tested with the example on : https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle

That works but i am in need of more complex data structure its not working anyway.Even though reloading the page. I am running this on : http://localhost:3000/about